# Parsing huge XML Wikipedia dumps with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, wikipedia

I am trying to parse Wikipedia history dumps from XML to PySpark Dataframe. When I parse a huge file (+100GB) on a cluster with 1.6 TB of RAM, I get OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit error (even though I am utilizing the whole RAM from the cluster, and I have tried a few combinations of executorMemory and MemoryOverhead). The XML file is structured as follows:

```
<mediawiki>
    <page>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>SomeTitle</title>
        <revision>... </revision>
        <revision>... </revision>
        <revision>... </revision>
        ...
    </page>
    <page>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>SomeTitle</title>
        <revision>... </revision>
        <revision>... </revision>
        <revision>... </revision>
        ...
    </page>
    ...
</mediawiki>
```

And my code is:

```
df = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='page').load("xmlfile.xml")
```

I wanted to have the 'page' as a rowTag because I need some information like title and id from the page (after that I want to explode the revisions to get a row per revision) . And, I think I get this error because some pages have too many revisions and they can't fit into the underling java array on the nodes.

If I use:

```
df = spark.read.format('xml').options(rowTag='revision').load("xmlfile.xml")
```

everything works, but I lose information about the pages like the title and the id etc.

Can someone propose an alternative way to parse the XMLs? Maybe use 'revision' as rowTag, but somehow keep the id and title from the 'page' tag. Thanks in advance.